# Recommended device for testing my own SDR?

Tags: software-defined-radio

I'm trying to implement my own SDR using Matlab. I was wondering what kind of device I could buy in order to test it. I know I can use my own soundcard but I was thinking of EM waves, not sound. Is there a device capable of functioning as transmitter and receiver and be compatible with Matlab? Just wondering, I have found very cheaps ones (like RTL-SDR) but they only work as receivers and I'm not sure if they're Matlab-compatible. Thanks!

Comment: Ettus has several products with Matlab support. none is inexpensive

Comment: Oh my! I think I'll stick with the soundcard then... lol

Answer (score 4):

For both receive and transmit SDR experimentation/testing at RF/HF/VHF/etc. frequencies, I use a [LimeSDR Mini](https://wiki.myriadrf.org/LimeSDR-Mini) (far less expensive than an Ettus). But I stream from/to it using C programs and files, not direct from Matlab.  (Is it possible to write a C stub to pass data back and forth with Matlab?)

There is also the [ADALM-Pluto](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/adalm-pluto.html) kit from Analog Devices, perhaps suitably priced for educational environments.  There seems to be some sort of [Matlab support](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/adalm-pluto-radio.html) for it.

Some amateur radio transceivers (Icom, et.al.) have stereo soundcard (audio IQ) ports for conversion from/to (licensed) amateur radio frequency band RF.

Added: Another solution for amateur radio HF band SDR experimentation is the Hermes Lite 2 open source kit transceiver

Comment: Assuming Windows, RTL-SDR needs a USB interface from C utilizing the hacked DLL of the RTL-SDR. I was able to read COM ports from MATLAB (for Arduino)... Worth a try for USB read/write too...?

Comment: For (non-expensive) SDR receive-only RF experimentation, there are also the RTL-SDR, AirSpy HF+, SDRPlay RSP2, and several others devices and kits.